# How to create a link like yii advance search in admin.php?

Tags: php, hyperlink, yii

How to create a link same like Advance search in Yii admin.php?
I like to make an another link to open on the same page with form. exactly same like advance search link.

Comment: You have to find it yourself by watching the code in yii advance search! Basically it's a div hidden and shown using javascript after the click on a button.

Comment: @darkheir, thnx for your reply, i understand the code by seeing it second time.. anyway thnx alot